# Using a method whose name is stored in a string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to execute a method whose name is stored in a string ...
for example

```
dim a as integer = warehouse.getTotalCount("item1")    'a is now equal to 100
```

but what i want to do is as so..

```
dim item1 as string = "item1"    
dim fctn = "warehouse.getTotalCount("+item1+")"
dim a as integer = run(fctn)   'and here a should be equal to 100
```

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now...

The functions may be coming from several different classes and I want to run the fully qualified name.
How would I do this without using a case select?

EDIT:
I am having trouble with

```
Type.GetType("warehouse")
```

or

```
Type.GetType("fctn")
```

Comment: Read about Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was taken from [MethodBase.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) and should give you a general idea of how to do it, it's in C# but is easily convertable:

```
Type magicType = Type.GetType("MagicClass");
ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[]{});

// Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of 100

MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");
object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{100});
```

Try something like this:

```
Dim myMethod = wareHouse.GetType().GetMethod("getTotalCount")
Dim res = myMethod.Invoke(wareHouse, New Object() {100})
```

Comment: Although it's copied from MSDN, it would be helpful you also showed how `magicType` and `magicClassObject` were created

Comment: @freefaller added more detail.

Comment: i am having trouble with
Type.GetType("warehouse") or Type.GetType("fctn")

Comment: if warehouse is the instatiated object try this:
`dim myMethod = warehouse.GetType().GetMethod("getTotalCount")`
`Dim result = myMethod.Invoke(warehouse, New Object(){100})`

Comment: warehouse.GetType Does not exist

Comment: did you copy the code exactly as I had it? Works for me,tell me the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @Ishey4, is `warehouse` the class name, or the variable name of an instance of the class?  (Just trying to remove a possible misunderstanding)

Comment: I GOT IT!!! FINALLY!!!!
warehouse is a class name... but kinda like Ric said...i had to create and instance of warehouse...
dim fix as new warehouse
after that it all seems to work!

Comment: I just used your code as a reference as it looked like you already had a warehouse object you were using to invoke a method!

Comment: no i never initalized the object... again thank you very much... sorry for the rookie mistake..